# What is the effective enhancement bonus increase for unlabelled special abilities?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting

I'm building out a magic weapon for a level 20 campaign, so I'm capped by the +10 maximum enhancement bonus. I'd like to add [Transformative](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/transformative) to it, but I'm not sure what enhancement bonus it's counted as - for the purposes of the maximum bonus - because it's listed under the +4 or +5 [column](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/). The same applies to [Dueling](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/dueling), so I'm including that in the question.

[Glamered](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/glamered) and [Impervious](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/impervious) are similar in pricing mechanics, but I'd generally assume them to be +1 bonuses since they're under that column. Now, however, I'm seeing two potential rulings on the subject of magic weapon special abilities that are not specifically listed as a "+X" bonus:

1. These abilities count towards the maximum enhancement bonus allowed to the weapon.
2. These abilities do not count towards the maximum enhancement bonus allowed to the weapon.

If it's the first ruling, what are Transformative and Dueling counted as? It's not specifically written down in their descriptions, as it is in other special ability descriptions (see [Flaming](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/flaming) for an example).

If it's the second ruling, which my gut feeling says it would be, I can't see a whole lot of issues with allowing magic weapon crafters to make their weapons particularly durable or able to look like (or be) a range of other weapons, if they're already making a +10 effective weapon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It’s not counted as any enhancement bonus, and it has no effect on the +10 limit. You can have a +10 item with as many flat-cost enhancements as you like, and it would still be a +10 weapon and still fit within the +10 limit.

In D&D 3.5e, a weapon also had a 200,000 gp limit (which a +10 weapon fills just by being +10), that could only be overcome by making it an epic item. Pathfinder did not retain this limit, or include any kind of epic anything.